# Removing duplicates scale up error

Tags: java, arrays, duplicates

I am trying to remove duplicates from an array. What I have works on an array size of 10([11]). Then i had to scale it up to 5000([5001]). I thought this would be very simple. It compiles but when  I run it it runs an infinite loop. I'm not sure if it's just taking a long time or something doesn't work.
The `sort.sorting` works.

```
public class work_on_it5
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        int array [] = new int [5001];
        int LB = 1;//declare the lower bound
        int UB = 5000;//declare the upper bound
        for(int x = 0; x < 4999; x++)
        {
            if(array[x]==array[x+1])
            {
                array[x+1] = (int)(Math.random()*50) + 1;
                sort.sorting(array);
                x=0;
            }

        }
        sort.sorting(array);
        for(int x = 0; x < 4999; x++) 
        {
            System.out.println(array[x]);
        }
        //median(LB, UB, array);
        //mean(array);
    }
```

Comment: What's with your indexing? I think there might be some misunderstanding here. `int[5001]` has 5001 elements, not 5000. Not sure why you're using `x < 4999` when it should be `x < 5000`, or better, `x < array.length - 1` since you need `[x + 1]`. You're on the safe side of off-by-one errors, but it's best to just understand it properly.

Answer (score 2):

The reason for infinite loop is because you are setting `x=0;`

```
for(int x = 0; x < 4999; x++)
        {
      if(array[x]==array[x+1])
            {
                array[x+1] = (int)(Math.random()*50) + 1;
                sort.sorting(array);
                x=0; //Here you are setting the value of x which is never changed resulting in infinite loop
            }
}
```

in your `for` loop

So every time when it enters in the `for` loop the value of the `x` is equal to `0`.

Also the declaration

```
int array [] = new int [5001];
```

so all the elements of the array will have the default value as 0 so the condition `if(array[x]==array[x+1])` will always be true and then the above scenario that `x` is always `0` will cause the problem. Change the logic!

**On a side note:-**

It is better to use `array.length` instead of hard coding the length of array in `for` loop.

Comment: Thank you but it does work. If they aren't equal it will move to the next one. the x = 0 is just a way of keeping the counter on the same spot until there is not duplicate. I will use the array.length. I'm trying to figure out why it won't scale properly. When I use small number it runs and works fine.

Answer (score 1):

***Why infinite loop happens:***

1 You declare an int array as follows:

```
 int array [] = new int [5001];
```

each element has a defalut value of `0`.

2 in the for-loop,  **`if(array[x]==array[x+1])`** will always `TRUE`. and then **`x = 0`**

```
 for(int x = 0; x < 4999; x++)
    {
        if(array[x]==array[x+1])
        {
            array[x+1] = (int)(Math.random()*50) + 1;
            Arrays.sort(array);
            x=0;
        }

    }
```

As a result, the program always compare the first 2 elements only.

```
Compare array[0] and array[1], they are equal. 
Reset x = 0
Compare array[0] and array[1], they are equal. 
Reset x = 0
Compare array[0] and array[1], they are equal. 
Reset x = 0
... ...
```

This causes infinite loop. Make some change and go ahead. :)

Comment: Why does it work with small numbers then? Seeing what you said it shouldn't work, why does it?

Comment: If I did this algorithm on the array but the array is already filled with random numbers, do you think it would work then?